Gitlab pages shows 404 error with any path
I use a self-hosted gitlab. I have enabled pages feature in my gitlab.rb file. My external_domain 'https://gitlab.my-domain.com' and my pages_external_url is 'http://pages.my-domain.com'. I've created a clear project from template 'pages/html', added runner on my linux machine and built an artifact. I can browse artifact's files in gitlab, but when i try to open index.html in pages, i get an 404 error. Please tell, which logs should I provide and how?
I tried to post /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_pages_access.log onto pastebin, but It didn't allow me to do it : (
